# Is there a per-project setting for "Notify on language exceptions"?

Tags: delphi, madexcept

Or perhaps a compiler/switch directive?

I had an existing project which after I installed MadExcept, would only show the MadExcept Exception Dialog upon an exception and that is what I wanted; I did not want to see the default Delphi Debugger Exception Notification.

The problem was that on any new project both the default Delphi Debugger Exception Notification and the MadExept Dialog would pop up upon an exception. Too many clicks to be made... Remember; I am lazy :)

I noticed the `Notify on language exceptions` setting was enabled and disabling it would then only have the MadExcept dialog popup but I would like to know why when it is enabled the pre-existing project would not popup the default Delphi Debugger Exception Notification dialog and the other projects would? Is there some sort of directive in code that may affect this or a project setting?

I am happy to disable `Notify on language exceptions` but I am curious to know how this per-project situation has come into being.

Comment: Have you configured MadExcept settings in this new project of yours? I don't have much experience with MadExcept but I'm guessing there might be a setting that determines whether MadExcept is the sole exception handler or it passes through the said exceptions to Delphi debugger a well.

Comment: @SilverWarior - I did configure it and also compared the config dialog for the projects screen-by-screen and also the config files themselves and they are identical. Unfortunately it seems that MadExcept does not have a setting to make it the sole handler. That is why this is so strange to me and leads me to believe that some way or another there must be a flag/setting to disable `Notify on language exceptions` per project

Comment: Now I would not have noticed this if it was not for the fact that I had `Notify on language exceptions` off by default on my previous installation of Delphi. This time I forgot about it and so the twilight zone commenced.